# Control groups applied during remote desktop access?

Tags: xrdp

I set up remote desktop connection to my XUbuntu machine 16.04 using xrdp. When I connect remotely and start Android studio, I get an error during one of the operations: *"/dev/kvm device: Permission denied"*. Running *"ll /dev/kvm"* tells me that owner is *root* and group is *kvm*. When I run *groups myUserName*, I see that I belong to group kvm. However, when I run "groups" (logged in as *myUserName*, as shown by *whoami*), I don't see *kvm* in the list of groups.

It seems to me that when I use remote desktop connection, a different set of groups is being applied to my user account, and I would like to figure out how can I effect it (i.e. how can I affect my membership in *kvm* group to not being stripped during remote access?)

Thank you!